# Sets and cardinalities

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

- *Note that if $A, B$ sets s.t $|A| \leq |B|$ then there exists an injection $f: A \rightarrow B$.*

> Let $A$ be a set and suppose that there exists a proper subset of $A$,
> denoted $B$, 
>  which satifies $ |A| \leq |B| $. Prove that $\mathbb{N} \leq A $.

So far I've noticed the fact that $B$ has to satisfy the same property as $A$. It smells like induction, since we can argue the same about $B$, and so on. However, I struggle to see how it's connected.

Thanks

Comment: What does the condition $|A|\leq|B|$ mean? (I know the answer, obviously, I'm trying to lead you there.)

Comment: There exists an injection $f: A \rightarrow B$. I apologize for the lack of clarity though

Comment: So, there is an injection from $A$ into a proper subset of $A$. That means that a function from $A$ to itself it's...?

Comment: *(And again, I know what the notation mean. I'm trying to lead you to the solution.)*

Comment: In fact, $A\supset f(A)\supset f(f(A))\supset\cdots$ so I suggest you draw a Venn diagram from there and see what things look like. And then prove rigorously that what you see is correct!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Is that related to what I mentioned? Since now I can see how to inductively use $f_{n}: B_{n} \rightarrow B_{n+1}$ and take $a_{n} \in B_n-B_{n+1}$ (when $B_{n}$ is a proper subset of $B_{n+1}$ and $a_{n}$ exists due to the assumption)

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't just "take $a_n$". You can very clearly choose which one you're taking.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes I can see it now, thanks